# Generate google service account credentials without key in Cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

How can I create credential without the service account key file?

My current setup.

I am calling cloud function  from application using

```
curl -X POST CF_URL -H "Authorization:  Bearer $TOKEN" -d@Key.json
```

In Cloud Functions

```py
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(request_json),
                                          scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            'cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials,cache_discovery=False)

policy = (
        service.projects()
        .getIamPolicy(
            resource=credentials.project_id,
            body={},
        )
        .execute()
    )
```

I am passing service account key as payload which has security issue. How can I avoid passing key file as payload.

Comment: You do not pass the contents of the service account JSON key file. That will not work. If you have enabled Cloud Function Authentication, then you need to pass an OAuth Identity Token as the Bearer parameter. Review these links: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating AND https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-identity-token

Comment: That correct. I am using "print-identity token" for authentication. My problem is how to generate credentials in cloud function for doing other stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cloud Functions (and in all GCP product), you have a feature name [function identity](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity). That means that you can choose the service account that you want to attach to the Cloud Function when you it run. If no one is defined, this one by default is used.

Thereby, a default identity automatically exists in your cloud function. You can perform simply this, as [described in this library](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html)

```
import google.auth

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']))
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a problem with cross project. My cloud function is deployed in Project B and I want to modify resource in Project A.  Project A service account has all the roles/permission. I am calling Project B cloud function from Project A.

Comment: Add the default service account email address (the identity) to IAM in Project B with desired roles.

Comment: Don't mix all up! You have authorization for calling the function (whatever the project) and you have the authorization of what the function can do (whatever the project). You can grant the Cloud Functions service account identity on resources of project A, even if you have created the service account in the project B. For the authorization on the Cloud Function, it's the same thing.

Comment: @guilaume. Thanks I got it. I was not thinking other way around .